# Where to put SFML Window in GameStateManager

Tags: c++, sfml, game-state

I have a Pong game using SFML organized after this [tutorial](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/cxx/game-state-management/).

This is the UML diagram from the tutorial.

[image: Diagram from the end of the tutorial]

Now I am not sure where I should put my SFML RenderWindow variable (and other things that might need to be shared between game states.

I have a PlayingGameState with a shared_ptr to a GameStateManager. So the right place should be the GameStateManager class. Or should I put it into the DirectRenderingGameStateManager and change the shared_ptr to DirectRenderingGameStateManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of your `sf::RenderWindow` should go in your `DirectRenderingGameStateManager`. You have it marked as `<<interface>>` in your diagram but you've given it variables, so I'm assuming it's really an abstract (or concrete?) class. Either way, there's no reason for it to go in `GameStateManager` as that interface has no correlation to graphics.

Generally, place things as low as possible in your inheritance tree and as high as needed. That is: No reason for `GameStateManager` to know anything about the `RenderWindow`, but sharing it netween all your `Drawable`s is asking for trouble.

Comment: So the `PlayingGameState` should have a `shared_ptr` to `DirectRenderingGameStateManager` instead of `GameStateManager` ? Thanks for your answer and sorry for my long delay.